# parsing XML data then plotting on map

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Hi I am trying to parse some raw XML data on Android then I want to plot the earthquake on a map but firstly I cannot get the lat and Lon to display....secondly I have no idea hot to plot this on a google map in android

here is some of my code

```
           [// extract the text between <link> and </link>
                        links.add(xpp.nextText());
                    }
                }
                else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:lat")){
                    if(insideItem){
                        //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                        lat.add(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));
                    }
                }
                else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("geo:long")){
                    if(insideItem) {
                        //extract the text between <geo:lat> and </geo:lat>
                        lon.add(Double.valueOf(xpp.nextText()));;
                    }  }
            }
            //if we are at an END_TAG and the END_TAG is called "item"
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To integrate the geo:lat and geo:long coordinates onto Google Maps, you can enter in whatever coordinates there are into a URI parser (instead of an XML parser) as demonstrated below:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

This specific example was used for displaying San Francisco.

Comment: firstly, thank you for your response, I would like to integrate the coordinates from pulled XML data. not hardcoded....I can't even get the geolat and geolong to appear on the display but I know that I am getting the values as I got an error earlier stating that I was using the incorrect type for "52.443" which was a coordinate pulled from the xml..I don't know why they won't display with the rest of the info...I corrected the type but still nothing

Comment: If you're getting something like "incorrect type" then you're definitely awfully close. Maybe the parser is specific about data types, for example maybe it was reading your coordinate as a string instead of a double/float, or maybe it has to be a certain amount of decimal places, like 4 instead of 3. That's all I can think of to help - hope it does help.